JEXL sort array of object
Looking to sort array of object in jexl.
[{"id":1,"name":"John","type":9},{"id":2,"name":"Doe","type":7},{"id":3,"name":"Doe","type":10}]
Sorting based on type.

You could try and run something like:
public static class SortingContext extends MapContext {
    /**
     * Sorts an array using a script to evaluate the property used to compare
     * @param array the array
     * @param expr the property evaluation lambda
     */
    public void sort(Object[] array, JexlScript expr) {
        Comparator<Object> cmp = new Comparator<Object>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                Comparable left = (Comparable<?>) expr.execute(SortingContext.this, o1);
                Comparable right = (Comparable<?>) expr.execute(SortingContext.this, o2);
                return left.compareTo(right);
            }
        };
        Arrays.sort(array, cmp);
    }
}

@Test
public void testSortArray() {
    final JexlEngine jexl = new JexlBuilder().safe(false).strict(true).silent(false).create();
    // test data, json like
    String src = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"John\",\"type\":9},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Doe\",\"type\":7},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Doe\",\"type\":10}]";
    Object a =  jexl.createExpression(src).evaluate(null);
    assertNotNull(a);
    // row 0 and 1 are not ordered
    Map[] m = (Map[]) a;
    assertEquals(9, m[0].get("type"));
    assertEquals(7, m[1].get("type"));
    jexl.createScript("a.sort( x -> x.type )", "a").execute(new SortingContext(), a);
    // row 0 and 1 are now ordered
    assertEquals(7, m[0].get("type"));
    assertEquals(9, m[1].get("type"));
}

